# Twilio Autopilot - Alphanumeric Field Type Question

Tags: twilio

I created a simple example to collect information when someone types in something like: GIVE missions where GIVE is the task and missions is an example alphanumeric field value. When I test this, the value of the alphanumeric field gets truncated to the first letter and capitalized.

[image: Simulator example]

In the Train area I have this: Give {test_var} where test_var is type Twilio.ALPHANUMERIC

I would expect to get the whole value back and not just the first letter.

Comment: hi there! What's your account SID?

Comment: According to a senior data scientist on the Autopilot team, "this is by design. It extracts the capital letter of non-uppercased words. If it’s MISSION, it would get all letters"

Comment: Thanks Lizzie.  So is there any way to get the whole string if they weren't caps?  Seems like a strange limitation unless there is another field type on the way that can handle lowercase too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio.ALPHANUMERIC follows the logic below:

1. It skips normalization if the value is in uppercase and contains alphanumeric characters and no spaces. E.g. `123DJENJ`
2. It normalizes number utterances to digits. E.g. `one two three` -> `123`
3. It takes the initials of word segments that do not satisfy the first criteria. E.g. `alpha beta charlie 12` -> `ABC12`
4. It handles cases like `yee as in echo` -> `E` to boost the performance in voice channels.

We will improve our documentation on this. Thanks for bringing this up.

In your case, you might just need to define a custom field type for `test_var` to collect what you want. For custom field types, Autopilot won't do any extra post-processing.

Comment: Thanks. Don't custom types require definitions for the available values?  These are going to be somewhat open ended, so defining all the possible values will not be possible.

Comment: @ScottSmith I see what you mean. Try to upload as many as you can and the ML model can learn better from the context and values of your input.

Comment: If you just need to collect whatever shows up, using Collect with no specified type can collect any open ended input will do it.